# Reputation tab shows accepted answer as another vote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-count, reputation-history

In the reputation tab (ordered by post), "accept" event is also counted as a vote. For example, in the image below, "2 votes" is mentioned but actually upvote count is 1. Is that by design or a bug? Just wondering what could be the reason.

[image]

**Update**: 
Its been a few days and by looking at the answer it looks like that not many users know if this is by design or a bug. So, I am re-tagging my question as a bug. I am not looking for a fix, just want to know from the SO developers if it is intentional or not.

**Further Update** (just to set the record straight for future reference):
The text "**votes**", which was causing confusion, has been replaced with "**events**" which seems more appropriate. Not sure when was this changed.

[image]

Comment: It's by design. Accepts _are_ votes, look at your raw reputation page http://stackoverflow.com/reputation for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bounties, downvotes, accepts are votes table, I assume this is by-design. If you look into voteTypes [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/2834/), you'll see accepts ARE in "Votes" table

Comment: Well so are Flags but I don't think most users conceive of them that way. Although it would be interesting to see them on that list :)

Answer (score 6):

*If* this isn't by design, please don't change it. I happen to like it this way. I'm fine with expanding the definition of "vote" in that context to include acceptance decisions, and it feels right to have acceptance rep included in that list.

Comment: This in indeed by-design, a result of how all votes are stored on the back-end.

Comment: @NickCraver - I understand and agree with the inclusion of other events in the list.  However, I don't think we need to redefine "vote"  - Why did you choose that name?

Comment: @Kevin - because they are votes, literally stored in a votes table.

Comment: @NickCraver - Only in the most literal sense of the word.  An accept or bounty could be considered a single, binding vote, I suppose, but the word usually means something different.  They may be implemented with a mechanism designed to store votes, but that doesn't make them votes in the traditional sense of the word.

Comment: @Kevin - Feel free to give us a better name, we actually asked the community for one when this first went out, a suitable alternative wasn't offered...

Comment: @Nick - I tried to in [my answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107180/reputation-tab-shows-accepted-answer-as-another-vote/107728#107728) - I think "awards" is great, as long as it's only applied to rep-increasing things, but "changes", "actions", and "selections" all seem to fit better than "votes"

Comment: @Kevin - you'd call a downvote an "award"? :)

Comment: Like "votes", it's technically correct.  However, it's better than "votes" because it works for additional things, like accepts, edits, and bounties, and, most importantly, it doesn't have a different meaning somewhere else in the system.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens for bounties:

[image: Bounty, accept, and 2 upvotes equals 4 votes?]

I think a different word than "votes" should be used in this context.  Votes are numbered on the [voters tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters), used to calculate the Civic Duty, Critic, Electorate, Suffrage, and Supporter badges, and there's a daily limit on them.  In all of these contexts, "votes" means "upvotes and downvotes".  It's confusing to use the word "votes" on the reputation tab and raw reputation page.

Perhaps "awards" would be a better word choice?