# In the reputation view accept and upvotes for same question are being shown separately

Tags: support, profile-page

Previously they used to be grouped together, but are now separate. Is this intentional? ( I am thinking it is a bug ) I don't like this way as the same question is repeated two times if the answer is accepted:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three views in that page: by post, by time, and graph.

You're looking at the ["by time"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526535/manojlds?tab=reputation&sort=time) view. Select the ["by post"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526535/manojlds?tab=reputation&sort=post) view and you should see the display you're expecting.

By post, collapsed:

[image]

By post, expanded:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realize that I had clicked that one. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is **by-design** as mentioned by [Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) in his comment to the answer of [Reputation tab shows accepted answer as another vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107194/166025).