# Possible bug when another answer is accepted - showing as rep gain till refresh

Tags: support, reputation

I have trawled through Meta for a while now looking at many questions (the search terms seem to mainly return questions where rep isn't awarded at all) - the closest I found was this:

[Reputation tab shows accepted answer as another vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107180/reputation-tab-shows-accepted-answer-as-another-vote)

As I use the site of an evening, I have noticed on many occasions that my tabs show a rep increase as if my answer was accepted - but when I refresh it shows that another answer was accepted. This is solved with a page refresh and doesn't bother me as such - just wondering if there is a bug somewhere in the code. This happens across all my browser tabs (I see the rep increase by 15) but if I hover over my login to get the *activity hover thingy* it displays my rep and accepted answers correctly.

I don't want to throw out my own red herring (it may be the only time that I notice it), but I think this might be only the case when the rep cap is hit for an evening.

This question isn't to complain or whine, just trying to help pin-point a bug in the code somewhere.

Comment: "my answer was accepted - but when I refresh it shows that another answer was accepted" - On [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280895/calculating-last-ended-week-in-php), for example, [that actually happened](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12280895/timeline). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280418/joining-multiple-tables-with-left-join) had the accept hopping back and forth [even more so](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12280418/timeline), so it might be coincidence?

Comment: (noting that the fact that the decrease in reputation from the unaccept isn't reflected immediately is by design)

Comment: @TimStone It might well be, I noticed it on a good few occasions, thought I would bring it up. Never knew about the timeline feature to check. Seems a rather valid answer :) I wouldn't have thought that people were so back-and-forth :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that this can be closed off without anyone else bothering with it, as Tim Stone correctly points out, this is working as expected as there seems to be a flurry of Accept/Un-Accept going on in a good few questions.

Appreciate the insight and learning about the timeline feature!